# Unable to load picture from resource

Tags: java, eclipse

[image]So I am trying to load a image file from a resource so that when I export my application into a jar file, it could be used.

Now I have read the documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html

But I still don't get it... How can I implement this in my code?

Heres a picture so you could also see my application tree:
[image]

I can't change the getImage to getResources as it needs something and I dont know what.

EDIT: this is how the image line looks like right now: Image pic = `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("src/klassid/Pictures/mario.png");`

This will load it from resources.

CODE:

```
  package klassid;

import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.net.URL;



public class Hero {
    static Main main;
    java.awt.Image pic = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Hero.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Pictures/mario.png"));
    //Image pic = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("klassid/Pictures/mario.png"));
    double height = 0, speed = 4;
    public static final double gravity = 9.81;
    double x = 25;
    int y, a;
    boolean left = false, right = false, up = false;

    public Hero(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void render(Graphics g, Main pohiKlass){
        g.drawImage(pic, (int) (x), (int) (500-(height*100)), 50, 50, pohiKlass);
    }

    public void the_jump() {
        long previous = 0, start = 0;

        while(true){
            start = System.nanoTime();  
            if(previous != 0 && up){
                double delta = start - previous;

                height = (height + (delta/1000000000) * speed);        
                speed -= (delta/1000000000)  * gravity;
                y = (int) (500-(height * 100));
                //System.out.println(y);
            }  
            if(left)
                x-= 3;
            if(right)
                x+= 3; 
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(height < 0){
                height = 0;
                speed = 4; 
                up = false;
            }      
            previous = start;
        }
    }
    public void liigu(int i){
        if(i == 38 || i == 87)
            up=true;
        if(i == 37 || i == 65)
            left=true;
        if(i == 39 || i == 68)
            right=true;
    }
    public void liigu2(int i){
        if(i == 37 || i == 65)
            left=false;
        if(i == 39 || i == 68)
            right=false;
    }
    public void getY(){
        a = y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Picture with project structure is nice idea, but code you are using should be posted in form of text, not picture.

Comment: Anyway "I can't change the getImage to getResources" can we know why? Also have you tried using `/klassid/Pictures/mario.png` as path?

Comment: I added my code with last edit. If I remove the /src infront of /klassid, the image will not load when I just run the program in Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

The Toolkit.getImage() have 2 methods, you should use the second one with URL as parameter and use your ClassLoader to get the resource and pass it on

```
  // I am assuming that your picture is in klassid/Pictures folder inside the jar file
  Image pic = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("klassid/Pictures/mario.png"));
```

I like to do thing step by step, so, first test the class loader to see if you can get the image separate from the Toolkit by:

```
URL imgUrl = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("klassid/Pictures/mario.png");
```

and simply do the System.out.println(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("")) to see the root path and follow that to your image/resources.  One thing that you should understand about getResource() is that it is as a mean to get resource at runtime relative to the class path.  In eclipse is what you set either bin or bin/classes.  And in the .jar file it is the top of the file structure.

Comment: I am getting this error with it: ´Uncaught error fetching image:
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getConnection(Unknown Source)
 at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getDecoder(Unknown Source)
 at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(Unknown Source)
 at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(Unknown Source)
 at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(Unknown Source)
´

Comment: Also, I had to change the path to src/Pictures/mario.png, it will not find it otherwize

Comment: This is because you moved the images file. Use this getResource("Pictures/mario.png"); and since you are running from eclipse, the getResource() will load it from the bin/classes folder as starting point, so there should be: bin/classes/Pictures/mario.png

Comment: Still no luck. Gives me a ton of unknown source errors. I tried the just Pictures version and also the bin version.

Comment: you can use this line, say inside the constructor, to verify the root path:

`System.out.println(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(""));`
from that root path you can follow to find your image, and it should be Pictures/mario.png

Comment: /C:/Users/Kaspar/workspace/Kodune-mang/bin/src/klassid/Pictures/mario.png,   this is the whole path and it still does not work. If I use my old method and use this path : src/klassid/Pictures/mario.png  ,  the image loads though. But that method does not load it in the jar file

Comment: can you tell me what is the print out for this: `System.out.println(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(""));`

Comment: This is the full path that works with my old method: `C:/Users/Kaspar/workspace/Kodune-mang/src/klassid/Pictures/mario.png`  if I put it into any other method, errors are thrown.

Comment: There is your problem, are you sure: `C:/Users/Kaspar/workspace/Kodune-mang/bin/klassid/Pictures/mario.png` exists?

Comment: No. I actually found that the picture is right inside of bin also. I went to it's properties and coped the exact location into my program and it still does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You should try moving your 'Pictures' folder by putting it directly into the Project folder.

Your folder layout should look something like this.

```
-Kodune-mang

       -src
          -klassid

      -Pictures
          -mario.png
```

You can reference the 'mario.png' image by using the path.

```
Pictures/mario.png
```

Since the file path system in java (or at least eclipse) will automatically start in the main project directory. It will be able to view the 'src' folder and its sub components, as well as the new 'Pictures' folder and its sub components.

Comment: If i right click on the folder and tell it to be added as a source folder, then it automatically gets the src/klassid infront on its name.

Answer (score 1):

Load it as a resource, why not?:

```
java.awt.Image pic = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Hero.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("klassid/Pictures/mario.png"));
```

Comment: It gives me a : Unhandled exception type IOException

Comment: With what error message? The code works on my Eclipse. Is the image in "klassid/Pictures/mario.png"?

Comment: I added a new picture to my OP. Both methods, the one with red lines in the bottom and the one commented out dont work.

Comment: Correct, you can't instantiate Image in that way because it throws an exception in a member variable. Move it inside the constructor.

Comment: I mean:     

public Hero(int x, int y) throws Exception {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        java.awt.Image pic = javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Hero.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("klassid/Pictures/mario.png"));
}

Comment: I dont know now, after doing it all,  first of all it just didnt work and secondly I started to get some errors for used characters, that I should change something to UTF 8 or it will not save.

Comment: UTF8? Maybe in the copy&paste from here to Eclipse, the latter got a hidden character.