# Read files from a folder inside a jar file on classpath

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have a project with a graphical editor (like GMF technology) and I need read a file placed on a .Jar library that is on the classpath of the project.

The VectorSync_1.0.0.201403121100.jar have a structure like :

VectorSync:

- icons/VectorSync.gif
- model/VectorSync.xml
- program/VectorSync.java
- META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

The .classpath of the project where i imported the .Jar File is:

```
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.scala-ide.sdt.launching.SCALA_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/home/jperezmedina/git/arom/arom-core/target/scala-2.9.0/aromslave_2.9.0-0.1.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/home/jperezmedina/runtime-EclipseApplication/DefaultProject.arom/lib/VectorSync_1.0.0.201403121100.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

I used this method to try acces a .xml file:

```
JarFile file = new JarFile("VectorSync_1.0.0.201403121100.jar");

BufferedReader input1 = 
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file.getClass().
        getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("model/VectorSync.xml")));
```

But the method used return all times `null`.

Could you help me to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Check this for more infos, if works for you upvote ;)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22203162/images-not-loading-when-running-jar-file/22203605#22203605

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look into the [`JarFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html) you will notice that it offers you the api to do so

```
JarFile file = new JarFile("VectorSync_1.0.0.201403121100.jar");
ZipEntry entry = file.getEntry("model/VectorSync.xml");
BufferedReader input1 = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(file.getInputStream(entry)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this approach?

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
```