# Add directories in to EXE file - EXE4J

Tags: java, exe, exe4j

I’m trying to make an EXE file from my java application using the exe4j tool.  I have successfully  built the JAR file of the project and also the lib directory.  Another directory named “img” includes all the image files used in the application; without this directory, the JAR file does not execute.

How do I connect this directory to the EXE in exej4? Or do I need to add this directory to the EXE file? How do I go about this?

Comment: Why don't you add the images into the JAR instead?

Comment: Yes it is possible, check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22203162/loading-resources-images-contained-in-a-jar-file-or-in-the-classpath