# Load from code file from web-inf\lib\*.jar

Tags: java, jar, classloader, web-inf

How to load (from code) required file (*.txt) from WEB-INF\lib\someName.jar?

I tried mechanism:

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(<nameFile>).
```

But it worked only when required file was in WEB-INF\classes folder.
Then i tried to create META-INF\resources folder in jar with required file. But it didn't give effect.

Comment: Why bother going all the way to the classloader? You could've just stopped at the class.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading resources (images) contained in a .Jar file or in the classpath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22203162/loading-resources-images-contained-in-a-jar-file-or-in-the-classpath)

Answer (score 0):

Try getResourceAsStream method on the Class instead of ClassLoader.

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(<nameFile>).
```

Just tested it this way and I got an instance of sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection$JarURLInputStream@89fbe3